# How to download file by using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have link [https://rarbg2021.org/download.php?id=lqm5bu9&h=a6b&f=MP3-daily-2021-July-21-Bass-[rarbg.to].torrent](https://rarbg2021.org/download.php?id=lqm5bu9&h=a6b&f=MP3-daily-2021-July-21-Bass-%5Brarbg.to%5D.torrent)
Could you, please, tell me How can I download the torrent file by using python? Or...Is there another way to download file from this site? https://rarbg2021.org/torrent/lqm5bu9